# Audio lectures of Hubert Dreyfus's 2008 course on Being and Time, Division Two

Tags: reference-request, heidegger

Apologies for the somewhat sordid nature of this question, but I have spent quite some time looking for this already, with no result.

> I am looking for audio lectures belonging to a course given by Hubert Dreyfus in 2008, on Division Two of Being and Time ("Philosophy 189").

I have listened to Dreyfus's lectures on Being and Time, Division One (see [webpage](http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~hdreyfus/185_f07/html/Index.html)), which was of considerable help in understanding the corresponding parts of Heidegger's work. However, I can't find the audio lectures for the follow-up course ([webpage](http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~hdreyfus/189_s08/html/home.html)). I do think they have existed -- and therefore very possibly still exist somewhere -- because they are referred to on [this page](http://www.learnoutloud.com/Podcast-Directory/Philosophy/Modern-Philosophy/Heideggers-Being-and-Time-Division-II-Podcast/25765). (It says to look at iTunes, but I couldn't find anything there.)

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using the content in iTunes U, but you need to use Google and search for it, it doesn't come up otherwise.
The course you are looking for is in Spring 2008 and you can listen to it here https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/philosophy-189-spring-2008/id461120614?mt=10

Division one is also there under https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/philosophy-185-fall-2007-heidegger/id461120554?mt=10

Apparently it does come out in search on iTunes U but it's not in the Philosophy category so you need to hunt for it manually, by going to the UC Berkeley front page and then going into Spring 2008 on the right. http://itunes.berkeley.edu